# Transpose data and delete repeted rows Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have a table in google sheets with +10000 rows.

The sample data of the tables is:

| Patient.Data.ID | Exam.Data.Date | Report.Textblock.Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 146689 | 9/1/2023 | Derecho |
| 146689 | 9/1/2023 | Izquierdo |
| 146689 | 9/1/2023 | Transverso |
| 112792 | 19/1/2023 | Derecho |
| 112792 | 19/1/2023 | Izquierdo |
| 112792 | 19/1/2023 | Transverso |

And I want to transpose the last column and delete the repeated ID rows.

Like this:

| Patient.Data.ID | Exam.Data.Date | Derecho | Izquierdo | Transverso |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 146689 | 9/1/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 112792 | 19/1/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Is there a way to do it without coding? If not, could you help me with the code?

Comment: Your `data` is not in javascript object or JSON format so not sure of the source.  But I think what you want is a table of unique patient ID and in the adjacent columns the`Report.Textblock.Text` items associated with that patient?  Is that correct?  It would be easier if you show sample spreadsheet data of patient ids.  See how to create a [Table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `transpose the last column 'Report.Textblock.Text' for each 'Patient.Data.ID' and delete the repeted rows of 'Patient.Data.ID'`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situations using your sample input value shown in your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The ample output appears to have one extra data column than the related header columns

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(a,A2:A,b,B2:B,c,C2:C,
       c_,TOROW(UNIQUE(c),1),
       {A1:B1,c_;
        MAP(UNIQUE(FILTER(a&"|"&b,""<>a)),
          LAMBDA(x,{SPLIT(x,"|"),TOROW(COUNTIF(FILTER(c,x=a&"|"&b),c_))}))}))
```

[image]